5 white wires in a ceiling light fixture
I live in half of a duplex built in the 80s. In my kitchen I replaced the ceiling light for an LED one. It doesn't come on right away, not sure why. The problem is that there are 5 white wires in the fixture. It is on a 3 way switch. I just don't understand why 5 white wires. Could it be there are more connected to that circuit? But there is another ceiling light it too has 5 wires on a different switch. So I don't understand why both have 5 white wires each?

3 or more white wires together in a wire nut are neutrals. White wires separately (or possibly in a pair in a wire nut) can be all kinds of other things. PICTURES PLEASE!

5 white wires from the fixture/light or from the ceiling going into the box?  House circuits pair white wires with black wires.  One white to one black.

In the box there is 1 black wire, one wingnut had 3 black wires and 1 white, the other wingnut has 3 white wires. Sorry I was wrong. Looks like there are 4 wires coming into the box. I'm no electrician, but that don't look right. I disconnected the light for now till I hear from you but that is the way it was. The 1 black and the 3 white connected to the light.

What you are observing is an old-style switch loop
The single white wire in with the black wires is a dead giveaway that what you are seeing is a pre-NEC-2011 switch loop that uses the white wire going off to the switch as the hot.  While you can go ahead and install your light onto this without altering it, it's no longer a legal configuration for new work because NEC 404.2(C) was added in 2011 to ensure that smart switches have neutral available to them instead of having to return their operating current back in a hacky fashion.

Do I need to group all the black together and the white together then connect the wires to the light off all of each of them. Or can I find and just run off the two wires that are connected to the switch? Thank you for your help.

@RobertJenkins, the single black should be connected to the black of the light. The white from the light should be connected to the group of white.

Thank you for that. I am guessing the 4 wires coming into that box are for that light, the dinning room, over sink, and in the laundry room. They are all basically in the same space. Still don't make sense to me.

I now have a different problem. When I disconnect the 1 white wire from the 3 black wires. Connect the 4 white wires together then only 1 black wire is live, all the time the other 3 are dead all the time. Do I need to change the wiring at the switches to get them working again? If so how do I wire them with the way the light is wired? Thanks.

@RobertJenkins don't disconnect the white wire from the black wires!  That white wire is carrying power to the switch instead of being a neutral!
